# making the combination of 2 fields unique and validate them in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a table called `contacts` that has `contact_id` and `user_id`.
I want to make the combination of these 2 fields unique and validate them. So what I have done in my migration is this:

```php
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->integer('contact_id');
$table->timestamps();
$table->unique(['user_id', 'contact_id']);
```

This makes the combination unique, and when I try to insert a duplicate with this code:

```php
Contact::create([
    'contact_id' => $request->input('contact_id'),
    'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
]);
return redirect(route('person-search'));
```

I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'contacts.contacts_user_id_contact_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `contacts` (`contact_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, 1, 2020-12-05 09:26:09, 2020-12-05 09:26:09))
```

Instead of this error, I want to make a validation for these 2 columns and show a custom error to my user. How can I write a validation for that?

Comment: Can you include your current PHP code which is doing the insertion?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: Why do you have a pivot table named `contacts`? This is not good practice and goes against Laravel's naming conventions. It should be called `contact_user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As explained in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures), you can write custom validation rules easily. The callback function receives the field's name and value, as well as a callback you can use to emit an error message.

So, just write something that does a database query for the two values. As a quick and dirty example I would never put into production:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'contact_id' => [
        function($k, $v, $f) {
            $result = DB::table('contacts')
                ->select('*')
                ->where('contact_id', $v)
                ->where('user_id', request()->user_id)
                ->first();
            if ($result) {
                $f("Duplicate value");
            }
        }
    ],
    ...
]);
```

Another option would be wrap the creation in try/catch and throw a `ValidationException` if the creation fails due to that error.